# My YouTube does not offer the options mentioned in several help articles

Tags: youtube

I have 71 videos on YouTube but when I go to video manager there are none there. Meaning I can't edit anything. Also when I hit 'add to' under a video it does nothing. Thirdly, HALF of one of my videos is upside down. Can I rotate just that?

Comment: 1. are you sure you're logged into the correct channel? http://youtube.com/channel_switcher

Answer (score 0):

Are you the owner/admin of this channel? If you have this level of access you will see a gear icon next to your YouTube profile (top right of screen). Click the gear to show the primary settings menu.

From there select the text link 'view additional features' toward the bottom middle of the page. Here is where you can view all the options, metrics, and a video editor. The left side menu has "Channel" which has several sub-menus including 'upload defaults' that you should check.

I've never seen upside down videos; photos yes, but not videos. Did these videos show upside down before you uploaded to YouTube?

I'd recommend keeping your videos private until you're satisfied with how they look. That way you can adjust titles, descriptions, thumbnails, and other settings before pushing live.